# In Visual Studio Immediate window, why do I get Equals/GetHashCode/GetType/ToString as IntelliSense options for Button object?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am in a Click() method for a Button, and the sender is a Button object.  I want to access the ActualWidth member of the said Button, but when I type "sender." for IntelliSense options, I get the following:

[image]

1) What are these options, and 2) why don't I get the following, which is what I am expecting?

[image]

3) How can I access ActualWidth through sender in the debugger?

EDIT:

In the Immediate window, casting sender to Button does not help:

[image]

Comment: ((Button)sender). will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because you are accessing your button object in an event, where it is received as an `object`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                           //^^^^^^^^^^^^
{

}
```

These methods (Equals, GetHashCode, ToString, GetType) are available with the `object` class, and that is why you are seeing only these.

See: [Object Class (C# - MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)

> Because all classes in the .NET Framework are derived from Object,
>   every method defined in the Object class is available in all objects
>   in the system.

*(Also see: [Not everything derives from object - Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx))*

To use the object as a `Button` you have to cast it to a button object like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        //use properties
    }
}
```

For your Immediate Window:

You are not using `()` while casting it, Cast it like:

```
((Button)sender).
```

Comment: @Sabuncu, modified the answer, you are not casting it properly, you are missing the `()`, cast it like `((Button)sender)` and then you will see the properties

Comment: I will be accepting in 7 minutes.  Cheers to Canada!

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast `sender` to type `Button`. It's `object` type when it comes in.